# How to enable or disable bitcode for specific library or SDK in Xcode project

Tags: ios, xcode, libraries, bitcode

I have many external libraries and SDKs in my project. And some of them does not support `bitcode`. So I have to disable `bitcode`. But some libraries like **ParseCrashReporting**, does require it to symbolicate the crash reports.

I want to disable and enable `bitcode` for specific libraries. How I can achieve that? Is it even possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can't. The library itself has to be built with support of bitcode. However, in case you have to ship you app right now and you don't have time for waiting while they update their library - you can disable bitcode support for your whole project. Once you have updated library with bitcode support - just enable it back on and update your app in the AppStore.

To enable/disable bitcode support go to Project > Build Settings > search for 'bitcode' in the searchfield > set to YES/NO.

Comment: Ok got it. What is the best practice to deal with this situation? There must be some workaround to tackle this situation.

Comment: Just as I stated. Or don't use this library if it doesn't support bitcode yet. Or see if it is already updated for bitcode. Or find sources and compile yourself - which I doubt you will find, but well, still an option :D

Comment: Build Settings -> All -> in search field type bit

Comment: If you can't find the setting for some reason, you can add a user-defined `ENABLE_BITCODE` and set it to YES/NO.