# how to disable bitcode for particular SDK added to project

Tags: ios

i have disabled bitcode to NO in my project. Now in AppStore, the dysm download link is not showing.
can we disable bitcode for specific SDK
Please give suggestions

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to enable or disable bitcode for specific library or SDK in Xcode project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32947236/how-to-enable-or-disable-bitcode-for-specific-library-or-sdk-in-xcode-project)

Answer (score 0):

It's simple, you can't disable Bitcode for a SDK.
The SDK itself needs to be rebuild with Bitcode enabled/disabled if you want to use it with or without.